# How to set a keyname (or keycode) as a hotkey for vlc?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, vlc

I want to map keycode 168 (KEY_REWIND according to `virkeycode` on ubuntu) to Shift+Left (as it's the default hotkey in vlc for "very short backward jumps") and keycode 208 to Shift+Right.

This keycodes are generated by my bluetooth headset when I **hold** the Next/Previous buttons on it. if I don't hold it (the next/previous track) keycodes are sent and picking up by vlc without any problem.

In terminal, `showkey` command gives me those values (keycode 208 press, keycode 168 press) but when I try to set them as either hotkey or global hotkey in vlc/preferences/hotkeys, it doesn't pick any key events and just waits.

How can I feed those to vlc?

Thank you!